# Crystal Reports 2008- How do I get the median of a summarized field?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, summary

I need a way to work around Crystal's inability to summarize a summary.

Data Sample: 
Shipment Number and Sum of $ Paid: 
shipment #1 $1089.34; shipment#2 $985.22; and shipment #3 $1002.87

I have grouped my data by Shipment Number and summed the $ Paid for each shipment. Different deliveries were on each shipment so I had to sum the $ Paid to get the total amount paid on each shipment. Out of this list of sums, I need to find the median. I know this would be easy to do if I exported to excel, but I need to have it built into the Crystal Report.

I know writing a simple formula such as median(sum($paid)) does not work. The error message "this field cannot be summarized" confirms that Crystal does not have the ability to summarize a summary.

Please help! Any work-arounds are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this by using Running total.

1. Take running total for paid and another running total for count then use both in a formula to find the median.

Comment: Can you provide the specific formula I would use? I'm not sure how the running total for paid and the count would be used to find the median.
For an example: 
Shipment 1: consists of Delivery A ($40) and Delivery B ($60). The sum for Shipment 1 is $100. 
Shipment 2: Delivery C ($20), Delivery D ($50), and Delivery E ($70). The sum for Shipment 2 is $140.

Comment: Shipment 3: Delivery F ($100), Delivery G ($120), and Delivery H ($140). Sum of Shipment 3 is $360. 
I need the median of the shipment sums (100, 140, 360). NOT the median of each delivery.
Can you further explain the solution and formula using this example?

Comment: You try the running total there you can specify where to summarize the values after first group or after all groups then take the count in similar way. I can't paste the screenshot of the running total here try checking google on how to create running total.